# Gulp task with babel and browserify + catching errors

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

My gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');

gulp.task('precompile', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/assets/react/app.react.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/javascripts/'))
});

gulp.task('browserify', ['precompile'], function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/assets/javascripts/app.react.js'])
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/javascripts/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/assets/react/app.react.js', ['browserify']);
});
```

How I can improve this if it's possible? May be I can write only one task with browserify + transform (babelify) + console.log on errors ?
At this moment, if I have parse error - gulp watching crashed.

Comment: btw gulp-browserify plugin is in blacklist

Answer (score 2):

Try plumber

```
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

/**
 * Helper function to amend the pipe when a build task fails
 * see https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-transform/issues/1
 * and: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/259
 * @param {string} err  the error string
 */
function onError (err) {
    gutil.beep();
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
}

return gulp.src('app/assets/react/app.react.js')
    .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
    .pipe(babel());
```

Also gulp-browserify is blacklisted. You can follow this tutorial for a more gulpy setup: https://medium.com/@sogko/gulp-browserify-the-gulp-y-way-bb359b3f9623

Comment: I try to use 'gulp y way', but this issue stopped me: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1191
Do you have work example with vinyl-transfrom and browserify worked together?

Comment: Right seem like they broke things again in 9.0.6. If you pin your browserify to 8.x or even probably 9.0.4 you'll probably be okay. My setup is identical to some of the comments on the issue, so it's definitely vulnerable to `b.bundle()` returning undefined behavior.

Comment: with 9.0.4 I have error 'write after end', this is my simple gulpfile without babel - http://pastebin.com/Qwrmu6pL
Any comments?) Can you show your gulpfile?

Comment: @MaxP The browserify portion of mine looks exactly like yours. I'm running it in production on 100k lines of JS without a problem. My browserify version is `"browserify": "8.0.2"`. Maybe you'll have better luck with that.. Versioning isn't the best part of node community